# Scalar potential intuitive understanding

Tags: vectors

Why is it that when we define Curl F, we associate a scalar potential, such that F = grad(phi).

Also, what is the actual physical meaning of gradient, curl and divergence. I know how to compute them. In my limited understanding, divergence has something to do with flow or expansion, and curl with rotation. But what is the intuition and real reasoning behind it all?

Thank you.

Comment: If $F=\textrm{grad}(\varphi)$, then $\textrm{curl}(F)=0$ (actually it is an equivalence), so I don't get your first sentence.

Comment: Oh, i get it now. There is no divergence and curl of a scalar field. But why we use curl (grad phi) = 0 and denote this phi as a scalar potential?